# Text and lines don't look right

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

Since I updated my video drivers, sometimes text and lines on the screen don't appear quite right. Everything looks fine with default drivers that come with Windows, but I had to update the drivers due to errors when using VirtualBox.

The symptom comes and goes. It's hard to tell what exactly triggers it, and what clears it is also somewhat unpredictable. Sometimes it will clear up when I choose another window, change the zoom level, or scroll within the same window. Sometimes it seems none of these work.

The system is an HP EliteBook 8530p with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3650 graphics. OS is Windows Ultimate x64. Below is an example screenshot showing the text distortion even as I write this post.

[image]

What could be causing this? I used AMD's detection tool to confirm I'd downloaded the right driver. Is there some advanced setting I need to tweak that might just not be right for my system?

Comment: Resolution is a possibility.. Windows ClearType? (Sorry if I'm shooting blanks.. just trying to think of things you can try)

Comment: Resolution is at the screen's native (1280x800). I'll give ClearType a shot.

Comment: Tried adjusting ClearType, then disabling it. Neither helped.

Comment: This might sound counter productive, but tried changing the resolution to something less, confirm; and then back to 1280x800. Maybe windows still thinks it is on a lesser resolution, even if the setting shows 1280x800. Also check on Jack's answer as rolling back driver may be a solution (although it may not help your virtual box issue)

Answer (score 0):

I would try an older version of the video driver if the new one is giving you grief. I have had issues before when updating video drivers. I did not check the site, but I would imagine AMD would have a prior version handy.